# Raspberry Pi; Asp.Net Core MVC NuGet Issues

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, raspberry-pi3, nuget-package

I tried to compile my program with my Raspberry Pi 3 and I got the error:

```
/home/pi/Documents/Programmierungen/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package DevExpress.AspNetCore.Spreadsheet. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
/home/pi/Documents/Programmierungen/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package DevExpress.AspNetCore.RichEdit. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
/home/pi/Documents/Programmierungen/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package DevExpress.Charts. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
/home/pi/Documents/Programmierungen/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware/PlaudertischSoftware.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package DevExpress.AspNetCore.Dashboard. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

In Visual Studio I got some issues with this UI Elements either.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? Those packages don't exist on nuget.org. Looking at DevExpress's website, only paying customers have access to their secret feed URL. You need to log in to see it, then add it to a nuget.config file as a source.

Comment: I've already done all that stuff. It's just one reference or something like that.  When I debug it in the browser it says now:  SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'dxButton'